# Sending message only to particular websocket peer

Tags: php, sockets

I am working on a chat website and running php socket server ( using standard php sockets, based on script from https://github.com/sanwebe/Chat-Using-WebSocket-and-PHP-Socket/blob/master/server.php )
its all works fine, but I want to do some extra bits and not sure how it can be done (if can at all)

So the questions are:

- Can I authenticate users trying to connect to websocket without them actualy creating connection and then sending login/authentication info via socket message?
- How can I identify conneted peers (know which user is connecting to which socket) without them sending some info via socket message.
- Can I send messages only to a particular peer connected to websocket server (That would be a main question)?

Thanks